# What costs are charged for EC2 instances in different AZs connecting through an ELB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

If two EC2 instances in different AZs talk to each other, there's a data transfer charge, according to https://www.quora.com/In-AWS-EC2-what-counts-towards-data-transfer-costs

Whenever an ELB is used, there's a charge per GB according to https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/classicloadbalancer/pricing/.

So how about if I have instances in AZ A talking to a pool of instances in AZ B with an ELB in-between -- do I pay the cross-AZ data transfer charge *and* the ELB charge, or only the ELB charge?

Answer (score 2):

Taking [EC2 Data Transfer Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/) into consideration you will pay both cross-AZ data traffic and data processed by ELB charges when EC2 instances are in 2 different AZs.